# Drop values after train test split

Tags: python, pandas, split

May i know how do i drop values in y_train that correspond to x_train after splitting data?

For example: I want to drop those values in y_train that are NaN for X_train['Current_ratio']

```
X_train['Current_ratio'] = X_train[X_train['Current_ratio'].notnull()]
y_train ???
```

Comment: you could use the `.dropna()` function at the end of your dataframe

Comment: but i am dropping na base on x_train which is a different df now

Comment: Ok I think I am confused on what you are trying to do. So do you want y_train to be something like this `y_train = X_train["Current_ratio"]` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
 X_train = X_train.dropna(subset=['Current_ratio'])
 y_train = y_train.dropna()
```

You better do that before splitting though